# sample SAML JSON idp provider for Access Management

Tags: sites-9.6, access-management

We are Upgrading CM 9.6. successfully installed the Access Management on Server Using [Powershell Script](https://github.com/avmgan/AccessManagementInstallationScript). We are followed the SDL Documentation [link](https://docs.rws.com/956379/780163/tridion-sites-9-6-main-documentation/saml-settings). to setup SAML Settings. we are having some queries while set up

1. As mentioned in SDL Certificates [link](https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml) we are having 5 certificates. we can add all the certificates or any specific.
2. for User Name Claim & Full Name Claim, can we Use any values or do we have any specific values?
3. for the Separator field we can give Column(:) only or azure:
4. By default which Access settings do we need to select?

can you please share any Sample JSON for the same?

Comment: Can you provide what SAML Idp provider you are looking to set up with Access Management?

Comment: We are planning to setup Azure SAML integration. below configuration we used in CM 9.1. <saml20IdentityProviders>
      <add name="azure" issuer="https://sts.windows.net/<TENANT_ID>/"
        uniqueNameClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"
        displayNameClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname"
        groupClaimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups" />
    </saml20IdentityProviders>

Comment: As per SDL Link https://tinyurl.com/mpchtwta we are tried to configure the url but in Azure we don't see any Authentication section on My Enterprise application. for CM 9.1. we created Enterprise application same as this link (https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/2019/01/20/sdl-tridion-sites-9-0-integration-with-saml-2-0-azure-active-directory/) can we create New Application for Access Management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to your question:

**A1:** If you open up the **Set up Single Sign-On with SAML** page in the azure, In step 3 **SAML Signing certificate** section you will see the **Certificate (Base64) Download** button, click the download button, and copy this certificate text to Access Management Certificate field of your azure SAML Idp provider settings.

[image]

**A2:** - No, you can't just use any values, you have to define your **Attributes & Claim** values what you want to expose to access management if you want to see those claim types and values. In the Access Management after the successful setup, if you click the validation button it will show you all the claim types and values. These claim types and values will differ based on each Idp provider.

[image]
[image]

[image]

**A3:** For the Separator field value, you can give any value.
Are users the same across these IDPs? if yes then you need a separator if users are different then you don’t need it.

**A4:** Access settings depends on your requirements and use cases.

Sample Azure SAML Idp provider JSON:

```
{
    "key": "AZURESAML",
    "name": "AZURESAML",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "description": "AZURESAML",
    "type": "SAML2P",
    "iconUrl": "/access-management/ui/idpIcons/Auth0.png",
    "accessControlList": [
        {
            "applications": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Access Management"
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Add-ons"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Tridion Sites Classic (UI only)"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Tridion Sites Experience Space"
                }
            ],
            "apiResources": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Access Management API"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Add-ons API"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Tridion Sites Content Manager API"
                }
            ],
            "apiResourceRoles": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Administrator"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Administrator"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Administrator"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "forwardedClaims": [],
    "parameters": {
        "$type": "SamlParameters",
        "issuerName": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/",
        "serviceProviderName": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/saml2",
        "singleSignOnServiceUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/saml2",
        "singleLogoutServiceUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/saml2",
        "certificates": ["xxxInHM4BFDujREyvxxx51/3/xneT49gAc00AbIxxxxxxxGLXQwdecHjskwVFTe73aq+H1vsrCQFsFfCNY+xxx"],
        "separator": "|",
        "usernameClaim": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress",
        "fullNameClaim": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/displayname"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Velu,Now Im able to create SAML provider but in validated screen, bottom of the page we have properties section is there, its showing some expiredate, its related to?

Comment: @Ajay - Good to know your SAML provider creation worked, answer to your question it can be a token expiration date from the IDP provider. nothing to worry about that. If that article helped to fix your issues. please upvote and accept to close this ticket.

Comment: I have tried with your sample JSON, it's not worked for me. i have changed Service proviername & separator. then it's worked. please verify & confirm.
Key: azure
Name: azure
Description: azure AD
Provider Type: SAML2P
Issuer name: https://sts.windows.net/<TENANT_ID>/
Service provider name: spn:<application_ID>
SingleSignOnServiceUrl=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/saml2/
SingleLogoutServiceUrl=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/saml2/
Certificate : <SignatureValue _X509Certificate>
Separator: : (given column symbol)